# Display only rows values in which the difference in between a column is below 30

Tags: r, select, filter, rows, data-manipulation

I keep trying unsuccessfully to select from an excel file a filter in which only the rows values where three consecutive row values in column'x' are below 30 units. For example, in the following table:

```
Name   age height speed
Helen  12. 1.20    40
Alan.  14. 1.40.   75
Hector.15. 1.25.   80
Ana.   11. 1.02.   81
Sophie.16. 1.40.   50
```

When the difference in column `speed` is below 30 within consecutive rows it should give as a result:

```
Name   age height speed
Alan.  14. 1.40.   75
Hector.15. 1.25.   80
Ana.   11. 1.02.   81
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

If your data is like this:

```
x = structure(list(Name = structure(c(4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("Alan", 
"Ana", "Hector", "Helen", "Sophie"), class = "factor"), age = c(12, 
14, 15, 11, 16), height = c(1.2, 1.4, 1.25, 1.02, 1.4), speed = c(40L, 
75L, 80L, 81L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Hope I got the numbers right:

```
    Name age height speed
1  Helen  12   1.20    40
2   Alan  14   1.40    75
3 Hector  15   1.25    80
4    Ana  11   1.02    81
5 Sophie  16   1.40    50
```

Then do:

```
x[diff(x$speed)<30,]
    Name age height speed
2   Alan  14   1.40    75
3 Hector  15   1.25    80
4    Ana  11   1.02    81
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: what you wrote will work for a small table, however, how to solve the issue when you have an excel with more than a thousand rows and you want to get the difference between three consecutive rows only? I thought about the following but it gave me error:

Comment: documentexcel <- read_excel("table.xlsx")
View(documentexcel)
rn <- rownames(documentexcel)
numberow <- nrow(documentexcel)
maxnrow <- numberow-3
i <- 0While (maxnrow >= i) {
x <- documentexcel[1+i,documentexcel$speed]-documentexcel[i,documentexcel$speed]
 y <- documentexcel[2+i,documentexcel$speed]-documentexcel[1+i,documentexcel$speed]
 z <- documentexcel[3+i,documentexcel$speed]-documentexcel[2,documentexcel$speed]
 if (abs(x) < 30 & abs(y) < 30 & abs(z) < 30 ){
  documentexcel <- documentexcel[, ]  
   i<- i+1
  }
 else {
   i<-i+1
  }
}
elif abs(a - b) >= 30:
  i = i + 1

Comment: Hey isn't this another question altogether? What I have written above works for the problem you defined. If there is something different or more complex you would like advice for, please post it as a separate question

Answer (score 0):

next time you publish here it is useful to post some toydata information like below:

```
rm(list=ls())
#### Toy data ###
dfnames<-c("Name","age","height","speed")
size<-20 # number of rows
name<-LETTERS[1:size]
age<-sample(20:26,size,replace=T)
height<-sample(160:180,size,replace=T)
speed<-sample(0:60,size,replace=T)
df<-cbind.data.frame(name,age,height,speed)
```

## Solution:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)-1){
df[i,"test"]<-(df[i+1,"speed"]-df[i,"speed"])<30
}
df[nrow(df),"test"]<-"last_row"
df<-df[df[,"test"]!=F,]
```

Comment: Thanks! I will add the information better next time

Comment: what you wrote will work for a small table, however, how to solve the issue when you have an excel with more than a thousand rows and you want to get the difference between three consecutive rows only? I thought about the following but it gave me error:

Comment: documentexcel <- read_excel("table.xlsx")
View(documentexcel)
rn <- rownames(documentexcel)
numberow <- nrow(documentexcel)
maxnrow <- numberow-3
i <- 0While (maxnrow >= i) {
x <- documentexcel[1+i,documentexcel$speed]-documentexcel[i,documentexcel$speed]
 y <- documentexcel[2+i,documentexcel$speed]-documentexcel[1+i,documentexcel$speed]
 z <- documentexcel[3+i,documentexcel$speed]-documentexcel[2,documentexcel$speed]
 if (abs(x) < 30 & abs(y) < 30 & abs(z) < 30 ){
  documentexcel <- documentexcel[, ]  
   i<- i+1
  }
 else {
   i<-i+1
  }
}
elif abs(a - b) >= 30:
  i = i + 1